# PostgreSQL delete from table skipping rows which can't be deleted

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given I have a big table, some rows from which are referenced from other tables, some are not and I wanna delete the rows which are not referenced, is there a performant and straightforward way to do that in PostgreSQL?

What I'd like to do is to delete, deleting rows which can be deleted ok, and skipping rows which throw foreign key constraint violation when trying to delete those.

The way to do it which I see as of now would be to do some joins on tables which can reference rows from the given table, thus finding out what is referenced and what is not, but that's a lot of read operations and a pretty fat query and I'd like to avoid that

Comment: `delete ... where not exists (...)`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that would be practially the same as my solution with joins no? because inside `(...)` I'd need to do subqueries to find out if referenced or not. What I'd like to is to somehow try-catch and just proceed if can't delete because of a FK

Comment: that'd also make a query for every row of the left table, which will be very slow if the table is large. Is there a more performant solution for large tables?

Comment: How do you know that? Did you try? Don't underestimate Postgres' query optimizer (and what exactly do you consider "large"?)

Comment: Yes, I did try that on a fat table (~10mln rows)

Comment: 10 million is not considered "large" these days. But without the code you have tried, it's impossible to suggest an improvement

Comment: As I've said - what I've tried is exactly what you suggest - delete from A where not exists (select 1 from B where B.foo=A.bar) with the only difference that the subquery is actually more complex, ideologically the same